# Automator: Add Attachments to Front Message error

Tags: email, workflow, automator

I have this automator service that takes files from the finder and executes the Add Attachments to Front Message workflow.

So I hit "answer" to a coworker e-mail in mail.app, type in my e-mail and then go straight to the finder and execute the service on a selected document. Unfortunately, the workflow fails with the result: There is no outgoing message.

Am I using this workflow properly ? Does Add Attachments to Front Message do what I think it does ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I tried this too, and there is something wrong with the automator action "Add Attachments to Front Message". I do have an applescript which runs as a service, but it does it the other way around.

You right click any file and click on the service "New Email With Attachment" and what it does is creates a new email with the file attached. You then can write your email with it already attached. Seems like that could work, no?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I use this workflow already when I initiate a conversation and want to send a file. However, sometimes, I need to send a file as a reply. I know there are other ways to proceed (attaching the file directly, dragging it, using the way you describe and copying the conversation or copying the file, etc.). But I am looking for a way to make the workflow work as advertised (most convenient). Thanks for sharing your experience. We now may begin to consider a bug in the workflow.